# Gradle: illegal repetition error

Tags: plugins, gradle, repository

just started to use artifactory so as to manage all the libraries that i use..therefore i had to have the artifactory plugin. I used the screencast tutorial at http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin and added the buildScript as follows to download the plugin..

```
buildscript { 

repositories { 

    maven { url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-release' 

        credentials { 
            username = "${artifactory_user}" 
            password = "${artifactory_password}" 
        } 
    } 
} 

    dependencies { 

        classpath (
            group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 
                                 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.1.0'
        ) 
    }
```

}

then in gradle.properties file in my gradleUserHomeDir, i have the following, the password is encrypted by artifactory.

```
artifactory_user=admin
artifactory_password={DESede}ifW8DYgu849GR8EnzUMOlj/L8cwy6FQfRZgHHTyj9L0=
artifactory_contextUrl=http://localhost:8081/artifactory
```

Then i ran gradle tasks. the plugin was downloaded yes, but something is going wrong. this is the output

The TaskContainer.add() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use the create() method instead.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'S:\src\JEE-Workspace\movieplex7\build.gradle' line: 47
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'movieplex7'.

  > Illegal repetition
  >   {DESede}ifW8DYgu849GR8EnzUMOlj/L8cwy6FQfRZgHHTyj9L0=

here is the build.gradle

```
buildscript { 

repositories { 

    maven { url 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/plugins-release' 

        credentials { 
            username = "${artifactory_user}" 
            password = "${artifactory_password}" 
        } 
    } 
} 

    dependencies { 

        classpath (
            group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', 
                            name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.1.0'
        ) 
    } 
} 

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'artifactory'


project.description = 'Java EE 7 Hands-on Lab'
version= '1.0'
group = 'org.glassfish.movieplex7'

artifactory { 

contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
publish {
    repository {
        repoKey = 'libs-release-local' 
        username = "${artifactory_user}" 
        password = "${artifactory_password}" 
        maven = true 
    } 
}

resolve { 

    repository { 
        repoKey = 'libs-release' username = "${artifactory_user}" 
                    password = "${artifactory_password}" maven = true 
    } 
} 


}

dependencies {

providedCompile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
//providedCompile 'org.glassfish.main.extras:glassfish-embedded-web:4.0'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

it suddenly worked when i put each property in its own line like this

`repoKey = 'libs-release'

username = "${artifactory_user}"

password = "${artifactory_password}"

maven = true`

Comment: I don't see the difference. Anyway, instead of `"${artifactory_user}"`, you can simply use `artifactory_user`. Same for the other properties.